# SQL server suggested an index that basically has all columns from the table- is this a good idea?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 7 columns:

- ProductId
- WarehouseId
- StockDate
- OnHandQuantity
- InTransitQuantity
- CreateDate
- CreateUser

One of my user's is trying to improve the performance of a query and has created an index that was suggested by SSMS. The index looks like the following:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX1_FactStock2016] ON [dbo].[FactStock2016]
(
    [WarehouseId] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([ProductId],[StockDate],[OnHandQuantity],[InTransitQuantity])
```

Now to me, it seems counter intuitive to create an index like this when it basically includes all columns from the underlying table (CreateDate and CreateUser are not relevant). Isn't this basically creating a copy of the table as an index (minus the two audit columns)? Is this actually going to have any impact on the speed?

Answer (score 1):

Such an index would be a covering index for all queries on the table.  For many, queries this could be the best index.

There are other options, such as a clustered index that has `WarehouseId` as the first key in the index.

Whether this is a good idea or not depends on your environment.  If your sole concern is the performance of this one user's query, then it sounds like a good idea.  Additional indexes do incur additional overhead for inserts, updates, and deletes (although indexes can also help the performance of updates and deletes depending on the conditions).  Adding more indexes requires a balance of considerations.  There is nothing *a priori* wrong, though, about having covering indexes for a query.

Comment: So why would a covering index that contains basically ALL columns of the underlying table (and not just to satisfy the query) be any more effective than querying the table itself?

Comment: If the key lookups back into the clustered index would be sufficiently costly that having the covering, non-clustered index is worth the cost. Two scenarios that I can think where that would happen off the top of my head. 1) the CE underestimates how many rows will be coming back, thus underestimating how many times the key lookup will happen. 2) when there are sufficiently many rows coming back where the CE says "nah… it's more efficient to use the clustered index even though you have this non-covering non-clustered index".

Comment: @Lock . . . Because of other conditions in the query.  The index could be used for `where` or `order by` conditions (or even to facilitate `group by`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a covering index like this is a redundant copy of the data,  It can also improve query performance by avoiding the key lookup.

Indexing decisions often involve trade-offs.  Evaluate whether the additional costs of storage and maintenance outweigh the gains in performance.  A frequently executed query that benefits from the index may very well outweigh the costs.

Answer (score 0):

This index suggestion basically means that, **for this particular query**, it would be better if table's clustered index would have been built on the `WarehouseId` column. Since you cannot have more than 1 clustered index on any given table or view, **sometimes** this excess can be well worth the extra space (and some additional performance degradation of data modification statements).

Whether it is beneficial or not, however, you can only decide for yourself and your system - there are no general recommendations on this matter that would fit every situation except SQL Server index usage statistics, and what you can get from it. Shop around for index suggestion scripts, there are plenty of them everywhere.

Comment: Ah got ya. That's the type of answer I was after. So if my clustered key had warehouse first (it's actually a compound key with 2 other fields), then it would not have suggested this index?

Comment: @Lock, maybe. There are some general recommendations on choosing a clustered index that are better to follow, usually (as narrow as possible, preferably unique, etc.). Just don't forget that if you change your existing clustered index in order to tune up this query, other queries that access this table will be affected, as well. And the change will not necessarily be good for them. Yes, it's a rather delicate process of balancing, to be short.